# Wildfly pass parameters to deployments

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, wildfly

I have one WAR file with application.
What I need to do is to deploy this WAR twice in one application server (Wildfly) under two different names - deployment1.war and deployment2.war. So far, this is no problem.

The application in the WAR is reading configuration from configuration file and the path to the configuration is currently hardcoded in the application. I need to change this so the deployment1.war is reading deployment1.conf file and deployment2.war is reading deployment2.conf file.

I don't want to keep two different source codes (differing only in the location of the properties file).

So my question is - is there any possibility to pass specific parameter to deployment instead of whole server? Or any other way how to parametrize concrete deployment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use overlay to override a file in your deployment thus using 2 different web.xml each pointing to the proper configuration file. https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#Deployment_Overlays